# Using textFieldDidendEditing to enable/disable a button swift

Tags: swift

For some reason I do not understand why my button will not enable when text are filled in.

This is how I have set it up.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    calculateButton.enabled = false

    panelWidthTextField.delegate = self
    panelsWideTextField.delegate = self
    panelHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelsHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelPitchTextField.delegate = self

}
// Disable button when text is missing
func textFieldDidendEditing(textField: UITextField)
{

    if ((panelWidthTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
        (panelsWideTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
        (panelHightTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
        (panelsHightTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) &&
        (panelPitchTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil))
    {
        calculateButton.enabled = false
    }

    else
    {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }

}
```

If anyone has a better way to do this function all help and tips are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    panelWidthTextField.delegate = self
    panelsWideTextField.delegate = self
    panelHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelsHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelPitchTextField.delegate = self

    // Disable button
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "textChanged:", name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        calculateButton.enabled = false
}
```

Put this function in your class

```
 func textChanged(sender: NSNotification) {

    if panelWidthTextField.hasText() && panelsWideTextField.hasText() && panelHightTextField &&  panelPitchTextField.hasText() && panelsHightTextField.hasText(){

        calculateButton.enabled = true
    } else {
        calculateButton.enabled = false
    }
}
```

> (myButton must be an outlet)

Let me know if it works

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for great help. Have been grinding my head on this for a while. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `textField.text?.isEmpty != nil` try using `!textField.text?.isEmtpy`.

Using the `!` (NOT logical operator) will return true if `isEmpty` is `false` (no text in the text field). 
Asking whether the `isEmpty != nil` will return true if `isEmpty` has ANY value (true OR false)